# Create a relationship between identical tables in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2013

First off, I am very new to Excel and am using Excel 2013

I have a report created in Excel. Currently the report requires users to copy and paste data into an existing table (old_table). I have created a database connection that loads the data into another table (new_table). These tables are identical.

I would like to be able to somehow link these two tables so that all the data in new_table gets populated in old_table because all the functions and macros reference old_table. I don't want to go through all the functions and update the reference. Is there any way to accomplish this? Or will I ultimately have to just do it the hard way and go through everything and change the reference to the new table.

Even if I deleted old_table and renamed new_table to old_table the reference would still not be the same one correct?

Comment: Can't you just go `=` in the old table and point to the cells of the new table? So if old table start in cell A1 and new table in cell N1 then in cell A1 just put `=N1` and drag that over the length and width of your table...

Comment: yes but if new rows were added to the new table, the old table would not update with the new data.

Comment: Create a data connection

Comment: I have a data connection. thats what new_table is connected to. If I could add a data connection to an already existing table I would, but since old_table already exists I dont think I can connect it to data. I tried, but it seems thats not allowed